# While implementing google admob native ads, "CanIgnoreReturnValue" issue

Tags: admob, native-ads

While implementing google admob native ads, but the native template module doesnot perform this import : import com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependency in your nativetemplate module gradle file
implementation 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.9.0'

This solved my issue.